# How to use primary selection with tilda/terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, clipboard

Let me make my question a little bit more clear.

I am a linux noob and still trying to get the feel on linux command line. I use `tilda` as my drop-down terminal.

Suppose, I enter a `command` in terminal and than I have to make a quick search of the result of the command's output. Let's suppose the output resulted in an error. Now, currently what I do is select the complete error and than `right-click copy` to copy the contents which I believe is not a effecient way.

So, while reading on internet I came accross that there is a `PRIMARY CLIPBOARD` feature in which whatever is under selection is copied.

My question is how do I enable this feature in my terminal(tilda or gnome) only or is this something in-built by default. If yes how to use it.

I want this feature only for my terminal and not for rest of all my applications if it is possible.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3348800/776084

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you just want a more efficient way to copy and paste, you can probably use `ctrl+shift+c` to copy from the tilda terminal to the clipboard.

Comment: I think what he wants is that to select text he doesn't have to use `right-click copy` he just wants that as soon as a text block is selected using mouse it automatically gets copied and than he just had to use `ctrl-v` to paste the content.

Comment: I think OP is talking about http://stackoverflow.com/q/3348800/776084

Answer (score 0):

Any selected text is automatically copied to the primary selection (default x behavior). All you have to do is to klick the _middle_button_ (2nd mouse button) in order to copy the text somewhere else. If your mouse does not come with a middle klick, you have to configure a substitute (some key, simultanous klick of left+right mouse button, tab with two fingers on touchpad).

Comment: You could be more elaborate how to create a substitute. Cheers.